# Does an email address domain require a dot?

Tags: .net, email-validation

I noticed that when constructing instances of the `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress` class, it does not throw an exception for the email string foo@bar. This surprised me a bit since I don't recall seeing emails where the domain does not have a . in it. Is the domain bar really valid email address syntax?

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=net-6.0) here that states "Although the MailAddress class accepts a mail address as valid, other mail servers may not accept the mail address.". Also, it states that "A simple address format of user@host. If a DisplayName is not set, this is the mail address format generated.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s nothing stopping TLD registry operators serving a records at the apexes of their TLD zones. For example, if Verisign (the operator of the `com` TLD registry) wished, they could add an A record at the apex of the `com` TLD zone – `com` would then resolve to that IP, and your browser would connect to that IP when you visited `https://com`.

Does any registry operator actually do this though? Surprisingly, the answer is yes.

- http://ai is a nice retro landing page for “Offshore Information Services”, who seem to maintain the .ai TLD
- http://pn serves an “it works” page; https://pn serves “hello world” (with an invalid certificate)
- http://uz serves a HTTP 500; https://uz serves the Uzbekistan ccTLD’s homepage (with an invalid certificate)
- http://мон eventually serves a blank page, but does also serve a favicon; https://мон eventually serves a default Apache landing page (with an invalid certificate)

Source [Shortest URLs on the Internet](https://jameswillia.ms/posts/shortest-urls.html)

Comment: None of these resolve for me, all NXDOMAINs :(